# How do I count the total of number of participants in this way?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

If I have these values in a table:

```
Description | number of participants | GroupId
------------------------------------------
Alpha          1                       34
Beta           1                       34
Beta           3                       34
Beta           3                       34
Charlie        1                       34
Charlie        2                       34
```

How can I query to get this result?

```
Alpha   11 34
Beta    11 34
Beta    11 34
Beta    11 34
Charlie 11 34
Charlie 11 34
```

This is supposed to represent the total number of participants for the same Id

SQL query I am trying:

```
SELECT description
    ,COUNT(1) AS Cnt
FROM Table1
GROUP BY description

UNION ALL

SELECT 'SUM' description
    ,COUNT(1)
FROM Table1
```

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum()` with `subquery` :

```
SELECT description, COUNT(1) as Cnt
FROM Table1
GROUP BY description
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SUM', SUM(Cnt)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) AS Cnt
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY description
     ) C;
```

However, in `SQL Server` you can use `rollup` :

```
SELECT ISNULL(description, 'SUM') AS description, COUNT(1) as Cnt
FROM Table1
GROUP BY description WITH ROLLUP;'
```

Based on sample output you are looking for *window* function :

```
select description, SUM(number_of_participants) OVER (PARTITION BY groupId), groupId
from Table1;
```

You can use sub-query if window function not supports :

```
select t.description, 
      (select sum(t1.number_of_participants) 
       from table1 t1 
       where t1.groupid = t.groupid
      ), t.groupid 
from Table1 t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total sum for all rows as mentioned in your expected output, you can use the `SUM() over()` window function.

```
SELECT description,
       SUM(number_of_participants) OVER () as Total,
       groupId 
from your_table.
```

OUTPUT:

```
+-------------+-------+---------+
| descritpion | total | groupId |
+-------------+-------+---------+
| Alpha       | 11    | 34      |
| Beta        | 11    | 34      |
| Beta        | 11    | 34      |
| Beta        | 11    | 34      |
| Charlie     | 11    | 34      |
| Charlie     | 11    | 34      |
+-------------+-------+---------+
```

If you need sum for each description, then use `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY )`

```
SELECT description,
       SUM(number_of_participants) OVER (partition by description) as Total,
       groupId 
from your_table.
```

OUTPUT:

```
+-------------+-------+---------+
| descritpion | total | groupId |
+-------------+-------+---------+
| Alpha       | 1     | 34      |
| Beta        | 7     | 34      |
| Beta        | 7     | 34      |
| Beta        | 7     | 34      |
| Charlie     | 3     | 34      |
| Charlie     | 3     | 34      |
+-------------+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(description, 'SUM'), COUNT(1) as Cnt
FROM Table1
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (description), () );
```